# How to add hash to url with React Router without rerendering?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I wanna open a popin inside a route, and I wanna add an hash to the url.

For example before onClick `https://www.example.com/home` after onClick `https://www.example.com/home#send-me-an-email`

Well it works but **React Router rerender the whole route**.

Am I doing something wrong with React Router ? Let's see my code below (I simplified the things)

`index.jsx` I am using BrowserRouter like everybody

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';

import App from './App';

const render = Component => {
  ReactDOM.render(
     <Router>
       <Component />
     </Router>,
    document.getElementById('root')
  );
};

render(App);
```

`App.jsx` I am using withRouter because I am gonna need history and location somewhere else

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, Switch, withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import Header from './components/Header';
import Footer from './components/Footer';
import Home from './views/Home';


const App = ({ ...props }) => {
  return (
    <Header />
      <section>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path={"/"} component={() => <Home {...props} />} />
          <Route path={"/home"} component={() => <Home {...props} />} />
        </Switch>
      </section>
    <Footer />
  );
};

export default withRouter(App);
```

`Home.jsx` unfortunately when I do `this.props.history.push({ hash: 'send-me-an-email' })` it will rerender the route component Home, no good

```
...
render() {
  <div>
    <button onClick={() => this.props.history.push({ hash: 'send-me-an-email' })}>
      Send me and email
    </button>
    <Popin 
      isOpened={this.state.isPopinOpened} 
      handleClose={() => this.props.history.push({ hash: '' })} />
  </div>
}
...
```

How not to make a rerender just because I added a hash to te same url ? Cheers.

Comment: The only solution I can come up is to make use of shouldComponentUpdate and return false when your case matches, with this case you will tell react to not update and it sould not re-render.

Comment: No you are wrong, this is not the React Class which rerenders, it is the router which detects a new route whith a new hash a closes the old route and reopens the new one lol

Answer (score 6):

Simply rely on vanilla JS:

```
window.history.pushState("object or string", "Title", "/home#send-me-an-email");
```

This will add an hash/route without rendering or reloading anything.

Comment: Your solution works fine (but it isn't detected by the hashchange listener). If you take a look at this https://github.com/ReactTraining/history#navigation are we talking about the same history ??

Comment: I think I am really doing right. And there is no other alternative. I am just going to use Redux to save my react state, and job is done ;)

Answer (score 4):

I also wanted to add a `#hash` to the URL without triggering a re-render.

I simply used the `useNavigate()` hook from `react-router-dom` v6.

```
const navigate = useNavigate();
navigate('#my-fancy-hash');
```

Then, I read this hash with:

```
const { hash } = useLocation();
```

One thing to remember is that, at that point, the value of the hash variable would include the # character. When I had to actually use it, I simply stripped it out with:

```
hash.slice(1)
```

That should give you the proper value. I hope it helps!

Comment: Is there a way to keep query parameters? It turns `site.com/page?query=searh`  to `site.com/page#my-fancy-hash`